# Country specific Url in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to create two different Url in Magento in order to be able to show different prices for the same product.
eg: http://example.com/uk and http://example.com/de.

Comment: You need to use the store views concept in magento. Create 2 stores and assign 2 diff URL to them. You need to do some more changes. kindly go through this url https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento-multistore.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?